# How to open the app and call the function on the home page when clicking a notification of the closed App in a Flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the flutter firebase messaging plugin

```
 firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      handleNotificationMessage(message);
    }, onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      handleNotificationMessage(message);
    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      handleNotificationMessage(message);
    });
```

this method working when the app is open
but I need to call this function "handleNotificationMessage" clicking the notification when the app is closed

Answer (score 0):

```
handleNotificationMessage(message) async {
    dynamic notificationData;
    if (message.containsKey('data')) {
      // Handle data message
      notificationData = message['data'];
    }
    if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
      // Handle notification message
      final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
    }
}
```